# Does my motherboard(GA-Z270MX-Gaming 5) support dual gpu 1080ti + 2080ti?

Tags: motherboard, dual-gpu

I have a machine with [GA-Z270MX-Gaming 5](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z270MX-Gaming-5-rev-10#kf) motherboard, now I am running a Zotac 1080ti mini GPU on it, can I add an extra 2080ti to it?

I noticed there are still slots available, but I am not quite sure about this.

Comment: What does the vendor support say?

Comment: @Kinnectus It's ZOTAC 1080ti mini that I'm using, for the 2080ti, it's not decided.

Comment: They mean the motherboard's vendor.

Comment: Have you asked the motherboard manufacturer what the motherboard will support? Perhaps contact them or join their forums? Have I missed something here?

Comment: I would tentatively say no, not a good idea. Reason: The motherboard has only one x16 slot, the other slots are x8 and x4 and they share bandwidth.

Comment: It wouldn't work in SLI for the obvious reasons, the 2080 Ti, would perform like a 1080 Ti (if it was possible to put it in SLI with a 1080 ti).  While 2080 Ti supports SLI it doesn't support the same SLI bridge.

Answer (score 1):

No, as you need 2x16 slots and your board only has one. Equal bandwidth required. Identical cards tend to be used for dual SLI

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

Two graphic cards need two x16 slots (unless using x8 to x16 risers) but not necessarily with 16 PCIe lanes, so **it is indeed possible to plug two cards** (which would have equal bandwidth as plugging into x16 and x8 would make both work on 8 lanes). So I'm afraid Johnny got confused about slot width and PCIe lanes.

As it have been said, SLI is not possible between 1080 Ti and 2080 Ti, they don't even share the same SLI bridge, but you could run a **dual GPU**, e.g. for deep learning with Tensofflow.

---

**TL;DR**

Yes, you can make a dual GPU (for deep learning typically), but not in SLI.

Comment: I am planning to use it for DL! If it works, I don't need to upgrade the motherboard.